# What does 就 mean in 你怎么就睡在这里了呀？

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

> 你怎么**就**睡在这里了呀？

Searching 就 up on the [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%E5%B0%B1) gives a pretty long list of usages, and I have no idea what (if any) is most applicable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sentence still makes sense, even if you remove 就.

> 你怎么睡在这里了呀？

Therefore, 就 is an adverb here, and emphasizes the verb, "sleep".

A few more examples are from 现代汉语词典:

> 表示加强肯定
>
> > 我**就**知道他会来的，今天他果然来了
> >     我**就**不信我学不会
> >     那**就**是他的家
> >     幼儿园**就**在这个胡同里。
>
> <sub>现代汉语词典, page 697</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Do a Search Q&A (on the upper right field) on 就 and you will find extensive discussions on this character.

Simply put: '就' in '你怎么就睡在这里了呀?' Means 'just'.

Without further context, 'just' in "Why are you just sleep here?' Can carry different meanings too. For example: 'simply; only; merely; right away; then; must' and so on. Or even as a particle for emphasis

Answer (score 0):

你怎麼**就**睡在這裡了呀? - figuratively,  "of all places, why are you sleeping here?" 
vs
你怎麼睡在這裡了呀?  - "why are you sleeping here?"

This is a very interesting question. In this sentence, I feel it's used to convey a sentiment for emphasis, similar to:
就是啊 就是啊! vs 是啊 是啊!

In preparing my answer, I went through a google search of my own. I did find this old post, and perhaps it could be helpful to you:
[How is 就 (jiù) used?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1903/how-is-%E5%B0%B1-ji%C3%B9-used)